# Zend2 Sql\Select add distinct

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework2

I have following code:

```
$sql = new Sql($this->tableGateway->getAdapter());
$select = $sql->select($this->tableGateway->getTable());

$where = new Where();

if(isset($xxx)){
    $where->equalTo('xxx',$xxx);
    $where->equalTo('yyy',$yyy);
}

$select->columns(array('my_column'));
$select->where($where);

$select->limit(30);

$stm = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$res = $stm->execute();
```

I'm a bit new to zend2, so however i try... i can't insert distinct. 
And I would like to use Sql\Select cause I like it :)

In principle i want to show first 30 results unique by 'my_column'.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$select->quantifier('DISTINCT')`

Comment: My man :) I'll accept, but in 11 mins as notification says :) I was going trough class but missed this. Thanks a lot!